# If an already mentioned word is ‘things’

Tags: definite-article

If an already mentioned word is ‘things,’ or a plural noun indicating things including a pen, and things consist of a pen and an eraser, is it grammatical to say ‘the pen’ even though I didn’t say ‘a pen’ or a word only indicating a pen?

For example: ‘Things: the pen and the eraser’

‘The’ here only indicates any things already mentioned, not previously specified by context or by circumstance.

Comment: No, I don't think so. "The things on the desk included a pen and an eraser."

Comment: Clarify this question. Instead of describing what previous sentences might have occurred, just say them clearly.